# Dynamic nested loops with dynamic bounds

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I have a LinkedList< Point >  points ,with random values:

```
10,20
15,30
13,43
  .
  .
```

I want to perform this kind of loop:

```
for (int i= points.get(0).x; i< points.get(0).y; i++){
   for (int j= points.get(1).x; j< points.get(1).y; j++){
     for (int k= points.get(2).x; k< points.get(2).y; k++){
                         ...
                         ...
     }
   }
}
```

How can I do that if I don't know the size of the list?

Comment: could you explain the logic behind the loop instead of us analyzing what it is supposed to do? And honstely i don´t get what this is supposed to do in the end.

Comment: I agree that we need more information on what you're actually trying to achieve. Your code looks like you'd end up with n nested loops for n points which is a receipe to quickly kill your application (your example values alone would result in 4500 iterations and you have pretty small differences between x and y here).

Comment: Looks like what you're doing will result in a stack overflow/out of memory. Are you maybe trying to run for loops individually, not nested? That could be achieved with a foreach on the points list.

Comment: The iterations will be millions. I am trying to solve a multivariable equation with constraints ex. x1*x2 + x3 +... + xn = 0 , 10<x1<20, 14<x2<30, ...

Comment: The only possible solution i´d come up with(keep in mind what @Thomas said) would be the usage of a recursiv function. while you could do the chained looping here, you would still be killing your application most likely

Comment: Can you write a sample code please?

Comment: Maybe frameworks like apache commons can help you to solve huge equations. Millions of iterations will most likely lead to an exception.

Comment: It's a small project, I just need what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way to solve equations like that with less cpu and memory consumption but a brute-force approach like your's could be implemented via recursion  or some helper structure to keep track of the state.

With recursion  you could do it like this:

```
 void permutate( List<Point> points, int pointIndex, int[] values ) {
   Point p = points.get(pointIndex);
   for( int x = p.x; x < p.y; x++ ) {
     values[pointIndex] = x;

     //this assumes pointIndex to be between 0 and points.size() - 1
     if( pointIndex < points.size() - 1 ) {          
       permutate( points, pointIndex + 1; values );
     }
     else { //pointIndex is assumed to be equal to points.size() - 1 here
       //you have collected all intermediate values so solve the equation
       //this is simplified since you'd probably want to collect all values where the result is correct
       //as well as pass the equation somehow
       int result = solveEquation( values );
     }
   }
 }

 //initial call
 List<Point> points = ...;
 int[] values = new int[points.size()];
 permutate( points, 0, values );
```

This would first iterate over the points list using recursive calls and advancing the point index by one until you reach the end of the list. Each recursive call would iterate over the point values and add the current one to an array at the respective position. This array is then used to calculate the equation result.

Note that this might result in a stack overflow for *huge* equations (the meaning of "huge" depends on the environment but is normally at several 1000 points). Performance might be *really* low if you check all permutations in any non-trivial case.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. Chears